# Bootstrap Selectpicker bugs out in center

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

I encountered a bug(?) for [Bootstrap Selectpicker](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/).

On Chrome (so far this happens only on Chrome) when selecting middle, you don't select the selectpicker dropdown, but the actual original select, like this:

[image]

As can be seen in the image, the original select drowpdown is picked and also displayed:

[image]

Anyone else experiencing this and knows how to fix it?

It can be selected only in the middle for around 10-20 pixels in width :/

Comment: Are you using a template?

Comment: It's a modal view in Laravel 5.3 but also happens in non modals

Comment: not familiar with PHP but i had a similar issue which was only present in chrome and safari browsers. it turned out to be a CSS property in the template i downloaded which i wasn't aware of.

Comment: Exactly what/which property?

Comment: Don't have access to the code anymore but i think it was  `-webkit-appearance` set to some wrong value. Are you using on click or hover? which ever one you are you using i would try to other one to see if the behavior changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to my site.ccs helped me as a workaround:

```
.bootstrap-select > select {
    z-index: 0 !important;
}
```

Apparently, the issue is with select's **form-control** attribute (if you delete it in code, the problem's solved), which adds z-index, that breaks it for Chrome.